# Show posts by tags excluding current post

Tags: loop, query, tags

I'm having some trouble trying to display current posts by tags and not adding the current posts. Here is my work in progress and I'm using a custom post type. I'm not exactly sure on what to add in order to exclude current post.

```
<ul>
<?php


    $packages = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'properties',  'tag' => $tags, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

    if( $packages->have_posts() ) { while( $packages->have_posts() ) {
       $packages->the_post();
            ?>

    <li>
        <div class="featured-image">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" alt="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">';  } ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >Learn More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </li>

            <?php
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<p class="post-notification">No New Articles</p>';
            }
?>
</ul>
```

### UPDATED CODE

```
<?php

global $post;

    $packages = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'properties',  'tag' => $post->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

    if( $packages->have_posts() ) { while( $packages->have_posts() ) {
       $packages->the_post();
            ?>
```

Comment: Try to output `$post->ID` content ... it could be empty, so your query does not work as expected. Adding `global $post;` after `<?php` line could help.

Comment: still the same, check updated code. I'm doing it on my localhost at the moment

Comment: `'tag' => $post->ID` is obviously wrong now, in your query. And did you tried to echo `$post->ID`? Has it any value?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really knowledgeable when it comes to php and backend. Yah I tried to echo '$post-ID' and it comes out nothing

Comment: Well, if `$post->ID` is empty, then `post__not_in` in your query arguments is ignored, of course. And query results will include current post... where exactly is your code placed? In what theme file?

Comment: I placed it single-properties.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29136/discussion-between-marek-and-clestcruz).